# Why are there 12 complex spin coefficients in Newman-Penrose formalism and not 20?

Tags: gauge-theory

The twelve coefficients are set up in the $B_{ab'}: $\begin{pmatrix} A&D\\C&A\\ \end{pmatrix} and $A, D, C$ can have notation $E,F,G,H$ for $l,m,\bar m,n$ where $\phi = E,F,G,H$. Then all the twelve coefficient equations are set up thus: $A=EH\phi-FG\phi$, $D=EF\phi$, and $C=HG\phi$.  So my question is why isn't there an $I=EG\phi$ and $J=HF\phi$ in a matrix: $$\begin{pmatrix}A&D&I\\C&A&D\\J&C&A\\ \end{pmatrix}$$  I'm looking for more of a conceptual answer which could lead me away from error.  Thanks.